# How to pass grep and echo combination command as if condition in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, scripting, grep

I have a line like below from a file finalinput.txt

Apr 9, 2021 10:52:35 PM EDT c1d99c1af08ce4ae:-4277b446:178b8700262:-8000-0000000000019a8b 1618023155272
I wrote a small code subtest.sh below

```
keyinput="c1d99c1af08ce4ae:-4277b446:178b8700262:-8000-0000000000019a8b"

for line in $(cat finalinput.txt)
do
if $line | grep "$keyinput" > /dev/null; then
 echo -e "$date $time\n" >> timeoutput.txt
fi
done

output :
 line 20: Apr: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: 9,: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: 2021: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: 10:52:35: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: PM: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: EDT: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: c1d99c1af08ce4ae:-4277b446:178b8700262:-8000-0000000000019a8b: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: 1618023155272: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: ###Update: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: Assignment: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: Milestone: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: Apr: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: 9,: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: 2021: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: 10:52:37: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: PM: command not found
./subtest.sh: line 20: EDT: command not found
```

please help where i am wrong

Comment: Check your script with https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Tried it.. Its showing good in this shellcheck
but on my local server its the same error

Comment: you are running $line as a command

Comment: got it .. thanks a lot  
 am supposed to give if echo $line | grep "$keyinput"

Answer (score 0):

You should first fix the obvious shellcheck mistakes:

```
Line 1:
keyinput="c1d99c1af08ce4ae:-4277b446:178b8700262:-8000-0000000000019a8b"
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.
 
Line 3:
for line in $(cat finalinput.txt)
            ^-- SC2013: To read lines rather than words, pipe/redirect to a 'while read' loop.
 
Line 6:
 echo -e "$date $time\n" >> timeoutput.txt
          ^-- SC2154: date is referenced but not assigned (for output from commands, use "$(date ...)" ).
                ^-- SC2154: time is referenced but not assigned (for output from commands, use "$(time ...)" ).
```

While fixing SC2013 read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . Read about when to use quoting in shell [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) .

> where i am wrong

The `$line` executes a command with the name resulting from the expansion of variable `line`. You want to pass the content of `line` variable as input to `grep`. You want:

```
if echo "$line" | grep "$keyinput" > /dev/null; then
```

but it's better to:

```
if printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -q "$keyinput"; then
```

Overall in bash you can:

```
if grep -q "$keyinput" <<<"$line"; then
```

and pragmatically the whle script is just reading lines from file... that's what `grep` does anyway.

```
if grep "$keyinput" finalinput.txt; then
```

Also `echo -e ....\n` is just the same as `echo ....`.